# Android Java: I need to save a bitmap alongwith name,mobile no.s to the contact list

Tags: android, bitmap, contacts

## Android: Java

I'm able to save name,mobile no.s to my Contact List.

- however, i'm Unable to save logo/bitmap to the (new item in the) Contact List.

Could you send me a snippet of code to save the bitmap/logo, too, to the Contact List?

Thanks,
Kumar

Answer (score 0):

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(People.NAME, "Serkan Ozel");
Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(People.CONTENT_URI, values); 

Bitmap photo = myImage.getBitmap();
if (photo != null) {
  ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, stream);
  People.setPhotoData(getContentResolver(), uri, stream.toByteArray
());

}
```